# error in following sql command i.e.Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`employee_meeting` (
  `employee_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `meeting_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`, `meeting_id`),
  INDEX `FK_meeting`(`meeting_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employee` FOREIGN KEY `FK_employee` (`employee_id`)
    REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_meeting` FOREIGN KEY `FK_meeting` (`meeting_id`)
    REFERENCES `meeting` (`meeting_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

Comment: Any other hints other than "Can't create table"? That's not much of an error to go off of.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your other two tables don't exist yet. The following does work:

```
CREATE TABLE employee ( 
  employee_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
);

CREATE TABLE meeting ( 
  meeting_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (meeting_id)
);

CREATE TABLE employee_meeting ( 
  employee_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, 
  meeting_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, 

  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, meeting_id), 

  INDEX FK_meeting(meeting_id), 

  CONSTRAINT FK_employee 
    FOREIGN KEY FK_employee (employee_id) 
    REFERENCES employee (employee_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT, 

  CONSTRAINT FK_meeting 
    FOREIGN KEY FK_meeting (meeting_id) 
    REFERENCES meeting (meeting_id) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Error 150 deals with foreign key errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Be prepared to encounter them pretty regularly when writing up a schema, as they are easy to make.

To ask the engine what the problem is, run the following command:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

That will show the latest error.

If that doesn't help, the just follow these general tips:

- Make sure the parent tables that the foreign keys reference exist.
- Make sure the columns are defined to be exactly the same in both the parent and child tables, with the exception that the child table could be NULL, even if the parent is not.
- Make sure you are using a unique constraint name... although that may in fact be errno 121. I see that error somewhat frequently too.

Usually the column definition is what trips me up. So make sure the parent tables contain `BIGINT(20)`, and do not have `UNSIGNED` or a different type like `INT(10)`.